# Excel VBA, If cell is not numeric and empty in a column, selected cell copy and paste to another column

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, numeric

```
A   B         C   
a   rm        rm
b   
c   
d   4000
e   5000
f   r1        r1
g   c1        c1
h   103
i   1.8
```

For example, in B Column, if cell value are not number, copy the value to C Column

how to make that code?

please, inquiry for that!

Comment: you can find your answer easily by search in google, please try first, then ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to find the last non blank row number of column A.
Then run a loop and check if the value of column A is numeric or not.

```
Public Sub M()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Worksheet name here")
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
lastrow = sh.Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = False Then
.Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: thanks a alot!

but, (.Cells(i, 1).Value) has error....

please, recheck it above problem...

Comment: replace 1 with 2 and 2 with 3

Comment: GOT IT! IT WORKS, THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

The formula to do it would be: =IF(ISNUMBER(CELL), " ", CELL)

For your case put this snippet right in C2 and copy it down: =IF(ISNUMBER(B2), " ", B2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

**Formula:**

`=IF(AND($B1<>"",ISNUMBER($B1)=FALSE),$B1,"")`

**VBA:**

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And Not IsNumeric(.Range("B" & i).Value) Then
                .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```